# How do I duplicate the "pattern" attribute for Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, input

I've got a client with an online store that's having issues with customers putting emojis and special characters into a certain text input field. We only want them to be able to use spaces, numbers, letters, and letters with accents and umlauts and such. When I tried this solution, it worked.

```
pattern="[ A-zÀ-ÿ0-9]"
```

Problem is, it works for every browser we've tested it on except for Safari. I'm a serious Javascript n00b; I've successfully written JQuery and Javascript functions myself that have done what I've needed them to do, but my problems are twofold:

1. How would I go about writing a vanilla JS or JQuery function that replicates this pattern's functionality?
2. More importantly (because the possible solutions I've seen have omitted this information), how do I actually link it to the input so that it works in the first place?

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Comment: No matter what you do client side you always need to sanitize server side. Very easy to submit anything regardless of client side script

Comment: Try to replace the space `" "` with `\s` in your pattern, and see if Safari picks it up

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! The answer startlingly easy. A polyfill, as per this site:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/

Here's roughly the code that I used. Turns out the other dev had already added the entire Modernizr.min.js script to fix another problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/js/Modernizr-2.5.3.forms.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" data-webforms2-support="validation" src="/path/js/html5Forms.js" ></script>
```

Links to both sites to download both Modernizr and HTML5 Forms, for the convenience of any users with this same problem.

https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses&q=input%20pattern
https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/html5Forms.js/tree/master